# quasiisomorphic groups and torsion

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Are there two finitely generated quasiisomorphic groups $G$ and $H$ such that $G$ is torsionfree and $H$ has torsion elements of arbitrarily large order?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does it mean for two groups to be quasiisomorphic?

Comment: I guess quasiisomorphic should be quasiisometric, right?

Comment: There is a notion of quasi-isomorphic groups but I would bet OP did not mean it.

Comment: The groups to check would be Tarski monsters with infinite central normal subgroup: is the extension class bounded or not. In the former case you get an example.

Comment: Two abelian groups $A$ and $B$ are called *quasi-isomorphic* if there exists subgroups $A'\subseteq A$ and $B'\subseteq B$ such that $A'\simeq A$, $B'\simeq B$ and $A/A'$ and $B/B'$ are bounded groups.

Comment: What is a bounded group?

Comment: An abelian group $A$ is called bounded, if it is of bounded exponent (that is, there exists $n>0$ such that $na=0$ for all $a∈A$). See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prüfer_theorems.

Comment: Here is a definition of quasi-isomorphism of f.g. groups: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136944 for the definition of quasi-homomorphisms of f.g. groups. A quasi-isomorphism is a quasi-homomorphism $f$ which admits a quasi-homomorphic quasi-inverse $f'$, i.e., both $f\circ f', f'\circ f$ are within bounded distance from the identity maps. In case of f.g. abelian groups, this notion is equivalent to the one mentioned by Dietrich.